# What is the equivalent of jQuery.active($.active) in Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

As the title suggest, I would like to know the equivalence of `$.active` to be used with the `Prototype` library.

I am using this to determine if there is any AJAX request in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Ajax.activeRequestCount` the value will be `0` if there are no active PrototypeJS Ajax requests.

http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/activeRequestCount/